# TaskStackBuilder issue on Galaxy S3 running 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to add a parent activity to the pending intent I'm setting in a notification.  I'm using a TaskStackBuilder to do this.

It seems to run fine on an emulator running 4.4.2 but not on my Galaxy S3 running 4.4.2.  On the s3 tapping the notification opens the top level activity as it should, but pressing the back button takes you back to the home screen rather than the defined parent activity.

Is there a bug in the S3 4.4.2 build or am I missing something?

My min sdk version is 11 and my target is 19.

Here's my code

**Code for building my notification**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("text here")
                .setContentTitle("title here");

Intent contentIntent = new Intent(context, MyDetailActivity.class);
contentIntent.putExtra(MyDetailFragment.EXTRA_ID, id);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyDetailActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(contentIntent);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MyDetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyListActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MyListActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm seeing the same behaviour on my S3 with 4.3.